# How to modify django cms multilingual middleware

Tags: python, django, django-cms

hey guys, im trying to internationalize my site, so i have the django cms multilingual middleware class in my settings.py , when viewed from brasil, the url changes to
www.ashtangayogavideo.com/pt/ash/homepage/ resulting in a 404, because my site is in www.ashtangayogavideo.com/ash/en/homepage, how can i configure the middleware, or settings.py, so that the language code is added after the /ash/ ? .

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to modify your urls.py, not your settings or middleware.